# LumenWorks CachedCSVReader and variable length "CSV" file

Tags: c#, .net, csv

I'm picking up on some code that a previous person has written and they have decided to use the LumenWorks CSVReader.

In the main, this works fine however I have come across an issue and I wonder if there is a creative solution to it than I'm not thinking of.

The problem is that the file the reader is trying to process is made up of a header and lines so it looks something like below - *(note there are no column headings in the file and the variable number of fields between the header and line)*

```
"HEADER", "HEADTITLE","FOO","BAR"
"LINE","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"
```

As the header only contains 4 fields as soon as the CSVReader reads in the next line it only populates 4 fields and not 10 as it expects all rows in the file to be uniform. In fact, for the whole file every line only contains 4 fields.

Whilst I can appreciate this is the most common and expected use case and the files are expected to be uniform I have no control over the inbound files. At this time I am trying to seek a solution that would not require me to use anything other than LumenWorks CSVReader.

Any LumenWorks users able to offer any suggestions how best to deal with the variable lengths?

Comment: While CSV has no formal specification, I would say this isn't really a CSV file.

Comment: I've used Lumenworks for years. Probably the fastest parser out there.  However, we could not get around this problem as well. The code is no longer supported, and has not been updated for almost 2 years. Rather than update the source, we opted for another parser that handles this problem.

Comment: I agree with Tim as well. The RFC says the field count should be the same, so this is technically not a CSV file. In addition to changing parsers, we have tried enforcing a strict format with clients as well.

Comment: Assuming all lines but the first are the same, you could break the file apart into two files, putting the first line in one file and the rest of the lines in another. Then you should be able to read both as a CSV.

Comment: @joshgo, was that a roll your own parser or one that is freely available?

Comment: @TimB, unfortunately the 2 lines specified can be repeated multiple times in a file. As I suspected as it's not a CSV file so it is going to require me to write something or source a parser that will cope with this problem.

Comment: If using another library could be an option, then take a look at [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/), specifically the MultiRecordEngine example. It should be able to handle your file.

Comment: CsvHelper has this feature. Let me know if you need sample code, I'll add below.